# How do I tell Unity to mirror my display, using the command line?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I find it awkward, slow, and cumbersome, when giving a presentation, to:

1. Plug in the video cable to my laptop
2. Open System Settings
3. Find the Display Icon
4. Select the "Mirror Displays" checkbox
5. Click Apply
6. Wait a second and then confirm the settings

Instead, I would like to just run a command or write a script that mirrors my primary display and applies in an "I'm feeling lucky" manner.

I've looked at [xrandr](http://manpg.es/xrandr), but haven't found anything promising...

Answer (score 2):

The option with `xrandr` for mirroring displays is `--same-as`. What you will need to configure as well is the resolutions. I have a laptop and a VGA external monitor. Doing `xrandr --output VGA-0 --same-as LVDS` mirrored the displays, but because VGA output is larger in resolution than laptop screen , the laptop screen got stretched too much. In other words, you may need to configure them to match in resolution. For instance, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101493/85039) on unix.stackexchange.com shows example:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --output LSVD1 --mode 1600x900 --same-as HDMI1
```